# Applying method of dominant balance directly to an equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

The non-linear equation $y''(x) = \sin k x y$ for $k\in \mathbb R$ cannot be solved analytically to yield a closed form solution. However, by applying the [method of dominant balance](http://books.google.com/books?id=-yQXwhE6iWMC&pg=PA83) one may obtain terms in the asymptotic expansion of the solution, for example,

$$y \sim \frac{n\pi}{kx} + (-1)^n \frac{2\pi n}{k^2 x^2} + \dots, \quad n \in \mathbb Z, \quad x \to \infty.$$

Now, if `DSolve` could find some non-elementary function that is the solution, I could simply compute the series at $x=\infty$, and I would obtain this. But in this case, *Mathematica* just gives up and results in no solution at all. In such cases, is there a way to instruct *Mathematica* to attempt to directly compute an asymptotic series solution to the equation?

---

It should be clear that by "method of dominant balance" I am referring to the *general* approach, rather than the specific case where $y=e^{S(x)}$ is an appropriate substitution (as in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Method_of_dominant_balance)).

---

(You may wonder why there are no arbitrary constants in the asymptotic series to this problem, and that is because they lie in the hyperasymptotic series beyond this one. I was able to set up the equation for the hyperasymptotic term, and actually compute all the terms in the series as *Mathematica* was able to solve that one in terms of Airy functions.)

Comment: Please provide a link to the general approach for the method of dominant balance instead of the one I wrongly added

Comment: @belisariusisforth Well, it's not exactly wrong, just that the one on the Wikipedia article is a particular version of it when that exponential substitution is actually useful. In general, one just makes some educated guess, plug it in, guess which terms to neglect, solve for the first term, and plug everything back in to check for consistency. If there is none, you go back to guessing which terms are negligible. Rinse and repeat.